# Code not working properly, image should be appearing but is not

Tags: javascript

Hey all so currently im following a tutorial, and messing around in an attempt to make a game like agar.io. Below I have included the code. So what should be happing is when I start a local host, a black canvas should appear with a white blob/circle in the middle, but whenever I run this code im only getting a black canvas. If its any help at all, im using p5 and atom together. I cant seem to figure out why its not working. In the post I have separated the code since they are separate. But they run together. Im not getting an errors. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
function Blob() {
  this.pos = createVector(width/2, height/2);
  this.r = 64;

this.show = function() {
    fill(255);
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r*2, this.r*2);
  }
}
```

---

```
var blob;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  blob = new Blob();
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  blob.show();
}
```

Comment: try adding `fillStyle = "white";` on the line before `fill(255)`

Comment: You've a few functions (`background`, `fill`, `ellipse`) you haven't included that might help in debugging - but at first glance it doesn't look like you are adding the blob to the canvas. Nowhere are you providing a context from the canvas to draw the blob with.

Comment: I'd also recommend changing this to a working example in your question so we can see what's happening so our answers are not conjecture.